# Race condition on incremental backups

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am planing to automate to take incremental backups on a range of sql servers from 2000 to 2012, on a variety of windows too.  This will be done with a vbs script that runs on task scheduler.  I want to know if there is a problem to occasionally start a new incremental backup when the previous one is still running or I must be sure that there is a lapse of time doing nothing.  The rest of details are covered, I keep all the files, and I test (restoring on other server) all the backups.

Comment: Why not just use SQL Agent?  Is there some sort of advantage or constraint in your environment that won't let you use Agent?  There won't be an issue taking differentials, you can take as many DIFFs as you'd like, just as long as you have the corresponding FULL backup that they apply to.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer Because with a serie of scripts we have more prestations than sql agent: We push a record flag, take backup, check the file localy, copy to remote location, restore on the remote location, check the flag, and send a mail on success. And the script, is "all versions" friendly. All what I mention, is for full backups, now I want to add support to do similar tasks on incremental backups

Comment: On SQL Server 2005 and later it's not an issue. On SQL Server 2000 differential and log backups are blocked by full backups. That being said: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html

Comment: Show the logic which your VBS script runs for these operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a problem to occasionally start a new incremental backup when the previous one is still running

**For SQL Server 2000**

You would not be allowed to start new differential backup unless the previous one finishes.

**For SQL Server 2005 and above**

You can start new differential backup while old one is still running but new one would be blocked by already running differential backup. The new diff backup will only start after old one has finished.

[This Blogs.msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2008/12/30/concurrency-of-full-differential-and-log-backups-on-the-same-database/) article and [this SE thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137310/what-happens-when-two-separate-processes-perform-a-full-backup-against-the-same/137331#137331) would help you in understanding similar behavior